# How do I center 2 divs with different heights vertically in a wrapper

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs within another container div. I want these 2 divs to be centered vertically in their parent container

```
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="div1"> some contents here</div>
    <div class="div2"> some contents here</div>
  </div>
```

Div1 and Div2 both have different dimensions and height specifically)

This is my css:

```
.wrapper{width:100%;
         display:inline-block;
         margin:0 auto;
         }

 .div1{max-width:760px;
       display:inline-block;
       margin:0 auto;}


 .div2{max-width:540px;
       height:auto;
       display:inline-block;
       margin:0 auto;
       vertical-align:top
       }
```

Contents of div1 and div2 are responsive elements(either images or a slideshow)

All I want is for Div 2 to be centered vertically in the main wrapper because it is a bit smaller than Div1.

Any leads where to start?
I am trying to avoid using top margins on div2 because it gets very messy on mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using flexbox. Here's a fiddle showing how it works
**https://jsfiddle.net/m0nk3y/xchy52u7/**

---

**CSS:**

```
    .wrapper {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 300px;
        width: 100%;
        background: green;
    }

    .div1 {
        max-width: 760px;
        height: 100px;
        background: gold;
    }


    .div2 {
        max-width: 540px;
        height: 50px;
        vertical-align: top;
        background: silver;
    }
```

Comment: thanks Gen but the divs do not have a fixed height. and both div one and div 2 have different dimensions

Comment: @MichelleDimwaite You can just remove the height. I added the height so it's easier to see what's going on visually in the example.

Comment: @MichelleDimwaite Can you tell me why you didn't vote my answer as the accepted answer if this solution worked? Thanks.

Comment: sorry Gene, I must have seen your respond and mix them up and i havent been here for about a day now. your answer definitely works well. Its good to have very different approaches that almost deliver the same results. Good for learning. thanks a lot once again and sorry for the mix up..

Answer (score 1):

```
.wrapper {width:100%;
   display:flex;
   margin:0 auto;
   align-items: center;
}
```

optionally, you may want to add `flex-wrap:wrap;` and `justify-content:` with a value of `space-around` or `space-between`

Comment: hi @git-e-up. Thanks for your suggestions but I must add, these 2 divs are in line. I tried your suggestion, div2 which has a smaller height does not center vertical. A practical example is say 2 videos or different dimensions 720p and 480p all wrapped in the main container. These 2 videos are responsive.

Comment: thanks @git-e-up. I think the justify content made it just what i wanted.. cheers...

Answer (score 0):

give the divs `width:100%;` and add `clear: both;` and make the container `text-align: center;` see code snippet

```css
.wrapper{width:100%;
         display:inline-block;
         margin:0 auto;
         text-align: center;
         }

.div1 {
    max-width: 760px;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
}


.div2 {
    max-width: 540px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    vertical-align: top;
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="div1"> some contents here</div>
    <div class="div2"> some contents here</div>
  </div>
```